# Amazon S3 batch job through boto3 - request invalid

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create an Amazon S3 Batch (not AWS Batch, this is S3 Batch operation) job via boto3 using S3Control, and gets the request invalid. I tired it through Amazon S3 batch operation through console which worked and I am trying to do it through boto3 to create the batch job. Attached is the code and error message.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


client = boto3.client('s3')
client_control = boto3.client('s3control')

client_control.create_job(
    AccountId='71652345619605',
    ConfirmationRequired=True,
    Operation={
        'S3PutObjectCopy': {
            'TargetResource': 'arn:aws:s3:::worm-all-bucket-inventory-embark',
            'StorageClass': 'DEEP_ARCHIVE',
            'ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus': 'OFF',
            'ObjectLockMode': 'COMPLIANCE',
            'ObjectLockRetainUntilDate': datetime(2115, 1, 1)
        }
    },
    Report={
        'Bucket': 's3-batch-ops-report',
        'Enabled': True,
        'ReportScope': 'AllTasks'
    },
    Manifest={
        'Spec': {
            'Format': 'S3BatchOperations_CSV_20180820',
            'Fields': [
                    'Bucket', 'Key', 'VersionId', 'TaskStatus', 'ErrorCode', 'HTTPStatusCode', 'ResultMessage'
            ]
        },
        'Location': {
            'ObjectArn': 'arn:aws:s3:::all-bucket-inventory-embark/agentwidget/2/2021-08-26T00-00Z/manifest.json',
            'ETag': 'fdc154f55282ef570cc9023068a72fc2'
        }
    },
    Priority=10,
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::716293619605:role/s3BatchOps'
)
```

Response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davefogo/Documents/Workspace/sprinters/AWS/AWS_CLI_Scripts/python-scripts/create_job.py", line 10, in <module>
    client_control.create_job(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CreateJob operation: Request invalid
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. I had to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the format in the report variable.

```
Report={
    'Bucket': 's3-batch-ops-report',
    'Enabled': True,
    'ReportScope': 'AllTasks',
    'Format': 'Report_CSV_20180820' <== this needs to be added. 
},
```

Additionally, ClientRequestToken is missing. According to [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3control.html#S3Control.Client.create_job),

> ClientRequestToken (string) --
> [REQUIRED]
>
> An idempotency token to ensure that you don't accidentally submit the
> same request twice. You can use any string up to the maximum length.
>
> This field is autopopulated if not provided.

ClientRequestToken can be added in the following way -

```
import uuid
...

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ...
    RequestToken = str(uuid.uuid4())
    ...
    response = clientControl.create_job(
      ...
      ClientRequestToken=RequestToken,
      ...
    )
    ....
```

Also you need to specify the region when you are creating the boto3 client as best practice.

```
client_control=boto3.client('s3control', region_name=[Region_Name])
```

I have documented my syntax of using create job in [S3 Control Create Job Invalid Request Error](https://medium.com/@agrawalsam1997/s3-control-create-job-invalid-request-error-d4f893b7d59b)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3control.html#S3Control.Client.create_job), the field `ObjectLockRetainUntilDate` should be a `datetime` object, yours currently is an `str` object. You could try changing it from `'2115, 01, 01'` to `datetime.datetime(2115, 1, 1)`

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tried your change but it still doesn’t work. Do you have any other ideas?